# Meteor and TDD in leaderboard application

Tags: tdd, meteor

I'm trying to make TDD in Meteor, according to this post http://blog.xolv.io/2013/04/unit-testing-with-meteor.html

I wrote my test.js, but when i start application, i obtain this error:

```
ReferenceError: describe is not defined
at app/test/unit/test.js:1:16
at C:\Programmi\Meteor\examples\leaderboard\.meteor\local\build\server\server.js:294:12
at Array.forEach (native)
at Function._.each._.forEach  
(C:\Programmi\Meteor\lib\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:79:11)
at run 
(C:\Programmi\Meteor\examples\leaderboard\.meteor\local\build\server\server.js:227:7)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need Jasmine or Mocha installed in order to use methods like describe, expect, toBe, etc.

As the author of the article mentioned in #4:

> Notes:
>
> 1. We now have a Meteor object. Hoorah.
> 2. When Meteor.Startup is called, the function is used to replace itself. This means in a unit test, if you refer to Meteor.startup, you'll get access to the startup function and can test it, as you can see in the server unit test below.
> 3. The collection constructor exists now and it keeps track of how many times a collection is created so you can make assertions, like in the model test below.
> 4. A prototype containing all the collection methods as per the Meteor documentation. **This will allow you to add spies with frameworks such as Jasmine or Mocha which expect the methods to exist before spying.**

Comment: Thanks Andrey, but after install Jasmine with

    "npm install jasmine-node"

problem remains